# Junit / Spring Boot mocking classes

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, junit

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializr, using embedded Tomcat + Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used :

Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE, Tomcat Embed 8.5.6, Maven 3, Java 8

I have this class
I have this junit test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestPersistenceConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class JdbcRemoteUnitRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcRemoteUnitRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private SmsConfig smsConfig;

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private NextelSMSSender  smsService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test   
    public void testGetAllUnits() throws DataAccessException, SQLException {        
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

the class NextelSMSSender:

```
@Service("smsService")
public class NextelSMSSender  {

    public final static String OK_STATUS_CODE = "200";

    @Autowired
    SmsConfig smsConfig;
..
}
```

.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("sms-gateway.properties")
public class SmsConfig {

    @Value("${sms.domainId}")
    private String domainId;

    @Value("${sms.gateway.url}")
    private String gatewayUrl;
..
}
```

But it seems that is not mocking the objects property, because when I package the app. I got this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field smsConfig in com.plats.bruts.NextelSMSSender required a bean of type 'com.plats.bruts.config.SmsConfig' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.plats.bruts.config.SmsConfig' in your configuration.
```

I created a mock bean named `TestSmsConfig`, tried to add `@Bean`, but I got a compilation error:

```
The annotation @Bean is disallowed for this 
 location

    @Configuration
    @Bean
    public class TestSmsConfig {

        @Value("fake.domainId")
        private String domainId;

        @Value("fake.sms.gateway.url")
        private String gatewayUrl;

         ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're autowiring smsConfig, but you do not appear to provide that @Bean in your test application context.

In addition, you are using @InjectMocks incorrectly - this should be used to inject mock objects into the class under test (your NextelSMSSender class, not SmsConfig).

To resolve, add a @Bean method in your configuration class to provide SmsConfig bean instances.

Replace @InjectMocks from the SmsConfig variable in your test class with @MockBean. SmsConfig is an autowired mock object, and not the class under test.

See Section 41.3.4 - Of the [Spring Boot Testing Features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) for more info:

> Spring Boot includes a @MockBean annotation that can be used to define
>   a Mockito mock for a bean inside your ApplicationContext. You can use
>   the annotation to add new beans, or replace a single existing bean
>   definition. The annotation can be used directly on test classes, on
>   fields within your test, or on @Configuration classes and fields. When
>   used on a field, the instance of the created mock will also be
>   injected. Mock beans are automatically reset after each test method.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this is your configuration:

```
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("sms-gateway.properties")
    public class SmsConfig {

    @Value("${sms.domainId}")
    private String domainId;

    @Value("${sms.gateway.url}")
    private String gatewayUrl;
..
}
```

If you want to use that configuration in your test, you should add it to your configuration classes...

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestPersistenceConfig.class, SmsConfig.class})
```

And not add it as @Autowired or whatever.